# e.force:navigateToURL not working in salesforce 1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, salesforce1-platform

I have a lightning component and a button in that and on click of which I want to navigate to a Custom Object Tab. This I achieved using following:

```
navigateToIntListView : function(component, event, helper){
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": "/one/one.app?customObject"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
},
```

This code is working fine in desktop. However, in salesforce1 , It is giving me error :

> You cannot view this page, either because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices.

What can be the solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To navigate to a object tab, you can use [navigateToObjectHome](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToObjectHome.htm) instead of navigateToURL.

```
var homeEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
    homeEvent.setParams({
        "scope": "CustomObject__c"
    });
    homeEvent.fire();
```

This event is handled by Salesforce1 as well as LEX.

Comment: can you suggest a way of handling namespace in this case?

Comment: Its mentioned in the link I provided in the answer, `myNamespace__myObject__c` is how you handle namespace.